# How to use one webpage to make different Model Request

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a webpage which gets displayed as a popup.It calls the model function and fills the table with the returned Model data.

Since `Model.GetActiveIncidentsAssignedToMe()` is the only difference between three webpages, is there a way that i can dynamically select which model method i can call to populate data?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="IncidentTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                Header for the table...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var incident in Model.GetActiveIncidentsAssignedToMe())
            {
                <tr>
                    Multiple fields ......
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It dont know if I understood you correctly, but couldn't you create a wrapping function for those three model providing functions and switch them by passing a url-parameter/route-parameter?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear in asking question.Let me try your suggestion.